# Question reg. creating a data service layer in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm not much familiar with WCF, I've a requirement to create a set of services that can do only CRUD operations with database. Can I use WCF Data Services for this? Is there any other better solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF Data Services are surely one of the best options you can have for your CRUD operations. You just need to expose your database tables with allowing all operations and expose webmethods. Some examplescan be found here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/restcrudoperation07182009063903AM/restcrudoperation.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg465173

Hope this helps.